YA book series about an orphan girl with violet eyes who finds out she has powers
I read this series probably 10 years ago. It has been driving me insane ever since wanting to reread it now.
It was about a girl with violet eyes whose parents had died. She thinks she's an ordinary girl but one day she goes to school and there's a guy who makes her skin feel like lightning is touching her. Finds out she has powers and he can help her. There's some memory in my head about like crystal balls and another world with magic beings and evil faeries.

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. I highly recommend registering for the site so that you can continue to gain points, and will find it easier to accept should you leave the site and come back.

As per an unaccepted answer to Book series with a cover of a girl with unusual eyes, who receives a crystal ball, perhaps The Fallen Star by Jessica Sorenson?


For eighteen year-old Gemma, life has never been normal. Up until recently, she has been incapable of feeling emotion. And when she's around Alex, the gorgeous new guy at school, she can feel electricity that makes her skin buzz. Not to mention the monsters that haunt her nightmares have crossed over into real-life. But with Alex seeming to hate her and secrets popping up everywhere, Gemma's life is turning into a chaotic mess. Things that shouldn't be real suddenly seem to exist. And as her world falls apart, figuring out the secrets of her past becomes a matter of life and death.

Indeed, her parents are dead or missing with her being raised by her grandparents. A crystal ball (a "Foreseer ball") is a plot point.

I walked around the room, trailing my finger aimlessly along the glass countertop as I gazed down at all the peculiar looking objects. On one of the counters, I spotted a crystal ball that looked like what Fortune Tellers use to see into the future. I peered inside it, curious if I’d be able to see what my future held. Violet ribbons floated gracefully in a sea of shimmering water. Through it, my reflection stared back at me. Apparently, I possessed no psychic abilities. Either that or this particular ball was a dud.

In her first vision, Gemma sees a Water Faerie, which she's told is a guardian of the Underworld.
